Metals behaving as dielectrics for certain frequencies
I'm studying the complex refractive index of material media, which is given by:
$$n_c=n+i\kappa$$
where $n$ is the refractive index and $\kappa$ is the absorption index. I interpret this as though $n$ accounts for the scattering inside the medium whilst $\kappa$ representes precisely the absorption, and altogether these two phenomena account for the material's extinction.
Nonetheless, when studying perfect conductors, I've come across this formula:
$$n_c(\omega) \approx \sqrt{1-\frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega^2}}$$
where $\omega_p$ is the conductor's plasma frequency and $\omega$ is the frequency of the light we are inciding on the metal. From this formula we know perfect conductors are purely absorbing $n=0$ for frequencies below $\omega_p$ and purely refractive for frequencies over $\omega_p$.
Therefore, for $\omega>\omega_p$, we have a nonzero $n$ and no absorption at all, just as in the case of dielectrics! How can it be that a perfect conductor, which has no bound charges, behaves as if it were a dielectric?

Why do you think $n$ accounts for scattering? It describes change of wavelength, not decrease of amplitude. Scattering causes decrease of amplitude with distance, thus is described by the extinction coefficient $\kappa$.

Also perfect conductors are not "purely absorbing", they typically reflect. Also, what do you mean by putting the condition $n=0$ in that sentence?

In what respect does the perfect conductor behave as dielectric? Perfect conductor surface reflects perfectly, dielectric surface typically doesn't.

@JánLalinský thanks for your comments! I'll try to answer them in order: (1) I might have used the wrong  term for scattering since I'm studying the subject in spanish. I mean scattering as in Rayleigh scattering. The incident wave is scattered in a different direction and that makes the refracted beam

@JánLalinský (2) by purely absorbing I mean their complex refractive index $n_c$ is a pure imaginary number according to the formula in my post

@JánLalinský (3) looking at said formula, we see that for frequencies over the conductor's plasma frequency, the metal's absorption index becomes null and we are left with a real quantity $n_c=n$, just as in the case for dielectrics. This is precisely the case for dielectrics, which are transparent ($\kappa=0$)

Rayleigh scattering happens on inhomogeneities of the medium, e.g. fluctuations of index of refraction in air or water due to thermal fluctuations or fine dust, or some dissolved molecules in a solvent. This scattered radiation goes into all directions, not like a refracted beam, which after passing the boundary, goes in single direction. Medium with single constant index of refraction is not expected to manifest Rayleigh scattering.
